# How would I correctly use arrays in this case?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I've created two classes, `Waitlist` and `Party`. The `Waitlist` class will work with a list of `LocalTime`s and have multiple `Party`s assigned to each `LocalTime`. It is unclear to me whether I should make an array of `LocalTime`s and an array of `Party[]`s or if I should utilize `ArrayList`s somehow or if a `HashMap` is a good option in this case.

`Waitlist.java`

```
public class Waitlist {

    private static final int N = 74;
    private LocalTime[] times;
    private ArrayList<Party>[] slots;
    private HashMap<LocalTime, ArrayList<Party>[]> list;

    public Waitlist() {
    // initialize variables

    //init `times`
    times = new LocalTime[N];
    slots = new ArrayList[N];
    int h = 9; // open
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        slots[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        times[i] = LocalTime.of(h, m);
        if (m == 48) {
        h++;
        m = 0;
        } else {
        m += 12;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: array and list are essentially the same thing. Both very different from a `Map`, which could represent a relationship. Spend some time researching and understanding the basic data structures and sample use cases - without that basis of understanding, it's not clear how we can explain differences better for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems here that a hash map will be your best bet. Because you have an association of a party to a time, you could set the key to be a time and the value would be the list. That allows very efficient retrieval of the list of parties when accessing by time (which I assume you will be doing) and merely iterating over a list. This will be faster than performing searches on two separate lists to get the associations. Also, HashMaps provide iterators for keys as well, so if you ever need the list of times, you have that available to you.

To be specific, your HashMap should look like this for its data type.

```
HashMap<LocalTime, ArrayList<Party>> parties;
```

At this point, getting a party is as simple as

```
parties.get(time).get(index);
```

I'm writing in a kind of pseduo-code at the moment as I'm not near my machine, but the general idea is there.

Comment: So I'll be able to use `LocalTime`s as indices logically then? i.e. `parties.get(LocalTime.of(9, 24))` will return the ArrayList of parties scheduled for 9:24?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly how it will work. And with small enough data sets you should see O(1) complexity of the retrieval of that array.